How to create custom attributes to reference them in a page.razor, like @page etc
Project Structure: Blazor Automode, .Net 8
To create a page in a blazor project you use:
@page "yourUrl"

I want to create my own page attribute for the exact permissions to be able acess a page like:
@page "/user/crud"
//this line below is what i believe it would be, but currently does not work
@permissions "[userRead, userWrite]"

Does exists a way to make it work? If so, how?
I've tried researching but the only seggestion i found was:
using System;

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class MyCustomAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string Permissions { get; set; }
}

@MyCustomAttribute(Permissions = "PermissionToWrite")
@page "/my-page"

<h1>Welcome to my custom page!</h1>

But basically does not work.

@jeb Just editted my question, I think the last code sample made everything more confusing. I don't want to set a page title, I want a way to leave written in the page.razor file all permissions related to that page.

Maybe you are looking for the Authorize Attribute ? [Authorize(Roles = "admin,moderator")]  for example in a component @attribute [Authorize(policy: "Admin")]

@jeb Maybe your suggestion will work, in my context i need all permissions to be written in my application, i cannot write them in azure or anything like that. I'll try what you just said

@jeb It didn't work, My index page:
@attribute [Authorize(Roles = "admin,moderator")]
My script that gets all @pages and supposed to get the authorize attribute:
link
I put it on a link bc of the limite of chars

@jeb before it wasn't working but now it worked perfectly!
if you like post your answer to my question i'll tag that as the awnser
